# How to remove a drive for USB-stick which is greyed out although no USB-stick is plugged in anymore?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, eject, windows-11-v22h2

Drives taken by USB-sticks remain greyed out (see `D:\` and `M:\` in screen-shot) although the USB-sticks are ejected properly by `Safely Remove Hardware`. The command `net use` does not list these drives which shows that they are not occuppied otherwise. How can I clear these drives to make them available for other connections?

Current OS: Windows 11 Pro, Version 22H2

[image]